# Bank database: correct definition of a relationship?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am building a Bank Application with Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA in which I have some problems with defining the relationship between BankAccount class with the BankTransfer class that I couldn't find a solution for. A bank account has a list of transfers `List<BankTransfer> transfers`. So here the relationship is defined as @OneToMany. But inside every bank transfer I have two BankAccount references called 'sender' and 'receiver'. The sender is the account from which an amount of money is withdrawn and the receiver is the account in which the amount is added.

Thus, every bank transfer has to have @ManyToOne relationship with the BankAccount class (the relationship is exactly Two-to-One relationship). So the difficulty here is how to map the two bank accounts (sender and receiver)? What to set as mappedBy field in @OneToMany annotation in BankAccount class.

Here are my classes:

The BankAccount class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "bank_account")
public class BankAccount {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "account_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "account_Sequeence", sequenceName = "BANK_ACCOUNT_SEQ")
    @Column(name ="id")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name ="account_number")
    private String accountNumber;

    @NotNull
    @Enumerated
    @Column(name ="type")
    private AccountType type;

    @Column(name ="currency")
    private Currency currency;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name ="balance")
    private BigDecimal balance;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name ="date_created")
    protected Date dateCreated;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                          CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name="client_id")
    protected Client client;

    @Column(name ="employee_id")
    private Employee accountManager;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               mappedBy = "sender",
               cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                          CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    protected List<BankTransfer> transfers;
}
```

And the BankTransfer class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="transfer")
public class BankTransfer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "transaction_Sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "transaction_Sequeence", sequenceName = "TRANSACTION_SEQ")
    private Long id;
    
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "amount")
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = BankAccount.class,
               fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                           CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "sender_id")
    private BankAccount sender;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = BankAccount.class,
               fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
               cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                          CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "receiver_id")
    private BankAccount receiver;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

As you see I have:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
                   mappedBy = "sender",
                   cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                              CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
protected List<BankTransfer> transfers;
```

in BankAccount class trying to map the `BankAccount sender` field in BankTransfer class:

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = BankAccount.class,
           fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
           cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
                           CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name = "sender_id")
private BankAccount sender;
```

I want also to map `BankAccount receiver` field in BankTransfer class. I tried for example this:

```
mappedBy = {"sender", "receiver"},
```

or tried to add 2 @OneToMany annotaions but these seem to be mistakes.

Can you help me with this problem. Perhaps I need to redefine my entities and oracle database tables respectively somehow. I am relatively new to RDBMS and I am building this application in order to gain more experience with them.

Comment: You need to divide the transfers into receivedTransfers and sendTransfers.

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on how you fill data on these entities.
If you create new data base, you can create `join table` and use `@OneToMany`.

Generally in cases like your I use only reletion on `BankTransfer` side, so you can delete transfers from `BankAccount`, especially you have lazy relation. Transfers from entity `BankAccount` you can realize by sql, jpa etc. you don't need field in entity

Comment: relations can be one directional, bidirrectional are not offen

Comment: Thank you, I did as you suggested - used just relation on BankTransfer and it works fine.